# Spring Aspect: surround entire method with try catch

Tags: spring, exception, aop

How can I create a Spring Aspect (annotation driven e.g. @ExceptionTranslation) surrounding an entire method and put this method in a try...catch method?

```
@ExceptionTranslation
public void method() {

    // do some stuff here...
}
```

so logically it does:

```
public void method() {
    try {
        // do some stuff here ...
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: look at @AfterThrowing aspect. here is an example http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-aop/aspectj-afterthrowing-annotation-example/

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find a sample implementation of AfterThrows advice solving your problem.

CustomException.java

```
package com.yourpackage;

public class CustomException extends Exception {

    public CustomException(final Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

ErrorBean.java

```
package com.yourpackage;

public class ErrorBean {

    @ExceptionTranslation
    public void translatedException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Foo");
    }


    public void notTranslatedException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Bar");
    }
}
```

ExceptionTranslation.java

```
package com.yourpackage;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExceptionTranslation {
}
```

SimpleThrowsAdvice.java

```
package com.yourpackage;

import org.springframework.aop.Advisor;
import org.springframework.aop.ThrowsAdvice;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor;
import org.springframework.aop.support.annotation.AnnotationMatchingPointcut;

public class SimpleThrowsAdvice implements ThrowsAdvice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ErrorBean errorBean = new ErrorBean();

        AnnotationMatchingPointcut pc = AnnotationMatchingPointcut.forMethodAnnotation(ExceptionTranslation.class);

        SimpleThrowsAdvice advice = new SimpleThrowsAdvice();
        Advisor advisor = new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pc, advice);

        ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory();
        pf.setTarget(errorBean);
        pf.addAdvisor(advisor);

        ErrorBean proxy = (ErrorBean) pf.getProxy();

        try {
            proxy.translatedException();
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            System.out.println("CustomException caught");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }

        try {
            proxy.notTranslatedException();
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            System.out.println("CustomException caught");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }
    }

    public void afterThrowing(Exception ex) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("***");
        System.out.println("Generic Exception Capture");
        System.out.println("Caught: " + ex.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("***\n");

        throw new CustomException(ex);
    }

}
```